# Issue with jquery append statement for timed greeting

Tags: jquery

In the middle of a college course for learning jquery and this week we are supposed to use jquery for a timed greeting.  I have previously done similar with straight JS to easy result.  However, I cannot seem to get the message to appear using jquery.  Below is the script tags with the code.  As I've been taught in the past these are both in the  tags.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var hrs = newDate().getHours();
        var greet;


        if (hrs > 0 && hrs < 12) {
            greet = 'Guten Morgan';

        else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 17) 
            greet = 'Guten Tag';

        else if (hrs >= 17 && hrs <= 24) 
            greet = 'Guten Abend';
        }
        $('.greeting').append(greet);
    </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot seem to find the issue.

Moved the script to the body and it worked, however, after adjusting the alignment of the tags it broke again. Even undoing the alignment changes failed to fix it.

At this point I'm totally lost.

Comment: You are having a syntax error at first line of script.`newDate` is considered as an object which is not available. You should use `new Date()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just syntax errors. `newDate` is a typo (should be `new Date`) and you have incorrect braces on your `if` clauses (you either need to omit the two `{` and `}` you did include, or include a full set of brackets on each clause):

```js
var hrs = new Date().getHours();
var greet;
if (hrs > 0 && hrs < 12) {
  greet = 'Guten Morgan';
} else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 17) {
  greet = 'Guten Tag';
} else if (hrs >= 17 && hrs <= 24) {
  greet = 'Guten Abend';
}

$('.greeting').append(greet); // This works, but append is usually for DOM nodes; 
                              // you probably want .html(greet) or .text(greet) 
                              // here instead
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="greeting"></div>
```

When working on javascript code in the browser, it is a good idea to *always* have the browser developer tools open to the console, so you can see error messages.

Answer (score 0):

First of all write syntax properly it means you have written wrong syntax. Before asking question debug your code. You may follow https://jquery.com for learning jQuery. You can write your code as following to append greet.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var hrs = new Date().getHours();
   var greet;
   if(hrs > 0 && hrs < 12)
    greet = 'Guten Morgan';

   if(hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 17)
    greet = 'Guten Tag';

   if(hrs >= 17 && hrs <= 24)
    greet = 'Guten Abend';

   $('.greeting').append(greet);
</script>
```